# Find number of logged in users in Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Is there a way to show the number of logged in users in Cognito?

I have gone to Manage Identity Pools but all I can see there is the total number of identities.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Cognito don't provide you these stats however you can create your custom metrics using one of AWS analytic tools such as AWS Pinpoint. Have a look at customer analytics [retention metrics](https://aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/customer-engagement/customer-analytics/).